# I have 6 functions that print the shape of letters in asterisks. I want to print these side by side

Tags: python

Define 6 functions using asterisks to print out the shape of the letters using for and if loops/statements.
The have a another function to take a user input, validate that the letters in the words are valid (have def's for) and then print each word in the asterisk form on 1 line then a new line for subsequent words.

This my attempt:

```
def A():
    for row in range(8):
        for col in range(8):
            if ((row != 0 or col != 0) and (col ==1 or col==7) and row >=2 or 
                (row==1 and col >1 and col<7) or (row==4 and col >0)):
                print('*', end ='')
            else:
                print(' ',end='')
        print()
def B():
    for row in range(8):
        for col in range(8):
            if ((row != 0 or col != 0) and ((row==1 or row==4 or row== 7) and (col>0 and col <7)) or 
                ((row== 2 or row==3 or row==5 or row==6) and col==7) or (col==1 and row>0)):
                print('*',end='')
            else:
                print(' ', end='')
        print()

valid_letters=['T','O','Y','N','B','A']
valid_words=[]
unique_words=[]

def user_choice():
    while True:
        user_input = str(input('Please enter a word only using letters "T,O,Y,N,B,A". Write "END" to stop. ')).upper()
        if user_input == 'END': 
            break
        elif [x for x in user_input if x not in valid_letters]:
            print("Invalid character. Please try again")
            
        else:
            valid_words.append(user_input)
    unique_words = list(set(valid_words))
    for word in unique_words:
        for letter in word:
            if letter == 'A':
               A()
                
            elif letter == 'B':
                B()
             
            elif letter == 'N':
                N()
                
            elif letter == 'O':
                O()
             
            elif letter == 'T':
                T()
               
            else:
                Y()
        print()
```

but  would like it to look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NFt7.jpg)

Comment: Wait. Did you write the conditional for an 8x8 matrix to produce a letter mask? It's an overkill. Just pre-define them as @paxdiablo described...

Comment: Each word has to be in an nx8 grid and each letter is to use iterations and conditionals. I am not allowed to to use print('***') line by line etc

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to implement a single function to *return a list of lines* for a given letter, rather than printing the lines. The `S` in the `SOLID` principles stand for "single responsibility" and this is a classic example.

By that, I mean it's better to have a function that works out what should be printed, and a *separate* means to prints it, allowing for the printing to be done in a great many ways without ever changing the "working out" bit.

For example, the following function provides a very limited sub-set of characters, just enough for the demonstration code that follows:

```py
# Get a list of lines for a given character. Ensure ALL are same
# dimensions or things may not work as expected.

def get_letter_lines(letter):
    blank, full = "        ", "********"

    if letter == "P": return [blank,
        " ****** ",
        " *     *",
        " *     *",
        " ****** ",
        " *      ",
        " *      ",
        " *      "]
    if letter == "a": return [blank, blank, blank,
        "  **** *",
        " *    **",
        " *     *",
        " *    **",
        "  **** *"]
    if letter == "x": return [blank, blank, blank,
        " **   **",
        "  ** ** ",
        "   ***  ",
        "  ** ** ",
        " **   **"]

    # What to give if unknown letter (or throw exception?).

    return [full] * 8
```

---

As an aside, that way of specifying characters seems a lot more readable (and maintainable) than the current method involving complex `if` statements. If I (as a developer having to maintain your code) saw this method, I would sing your praises for eternity because you made it so simple to change or add to :-)

---

But, regardless of how you do the individual letters (if, for example, you're *required* to use `if` statements), the crux is to return line lists for later printing. Then you can write a function that will handle a *string* of letters and get the line lists for them all, outputting all the first lines on one line, all the second lines on the next, and so on, something like:

```py
def print_string(text):
    all_chars = [get_letter_lines(item) for item in text]
    for line_num in range(len(all_chars[0])):
        print(" ".join([all_chars[idx][line_num] for idx in range(len(all_chars))]))
```

Then, were you to write some code containing `print_string("Pax")`, you would see:

```
 ******
 *     *
 *     *   **** *  **   **
 ******   *    **   ** **
 *        *     *    ***
 *        *    **   ** **
 *         **** *  **   **
```

---

Of course, this is the sort of thing that calls out for a *class* to do the heavy lifting. You should just be able to instantiate an object to set up everything needed then call a a member function with a string to easily give you lines to print.

Consider the following class, just the `__init__` function first:

```py
class Letters:
    def __init__(self):
        # Cache everything for efficiency.

        self._height = 8
        self._width = 8
        self._blank = " " * self._width
        self._full = "*" * self._width

        # Provide character mappings as needed.

        self._lookup = {
            "P": [self._blank,
                " ****** ",
                " *     *",
                " *     *",
                " ****** ",
                " *      ",
                " *      ",
                " *      "],
            "a": [self._blank, self._blank, self._blank,
                "  **** *",
                " *    **",
                " *     *",
                " *    **",
                "  **** *"],
            "x": [self._blank, self._blank, self._blank,
                " **   **",
                "  ** ** ",
                "   ***  ",
                "  ** ** ",
                " **   **"]
        }

        # Check for height/width problems with above mappings.

        for key, value in self._lookup.items():
            assert len(value) == self._height
            for line in value:
                assert len(line) == self._width
```

This is very similar to the previous non-class code but it has the following advantages:

- It can easily check you've got the widths and heights of everything correct, otherwise it won't even instantiate.
- It uses cached information to map character to letter lines so it can then simply do dictionary lookup.

Now we'll add the lookup code (still as part of this class), starting with a "private" function to get a line list for a *single* character.

It simply grabs the line list from the mapping that was set up in the constructor, or returns a default one if the character is not in the mapping:

```py
    def _get_char_lines(self, text):
        assert len(text) == 1
        try:
            return self._lookup[text]
        except KeyError:
            return [self._full] * self._height
```

Then we provide a function that does the same job for a string of characters, by combining the Nth line of each character into a single Nth line for the string (space separated):

```py
    def get_lines(self, text):
        chars = [self._get_char_lines(_) for _ in text]
        lines = [""] * self._height
        for line in range(self._height):
            for idx in range(len(chars)):
                if lines[line] != " ":
                    lines[line] += " "
                lines[line] += chars[idx][line]
        return lines
```

And, finally, to honor the `SOLID` principles, we still separate line creation from line printing. The printing is outside the purview of the class, otherwise how many different printing options should the class contain?

The class is simply responsible for providing what *could* be printed, leaving it up to the caller to decide the method. That's not too bad since the method is now very simple:

```py
# OPTION 1:

def print_string(letters, text):
    for line in letters.get_lines(text):
        print(line)

letters = Letters()
print_lines(letters.get_lines("Pax"))

# OPTION 2:

letters = Letters()
for line in letters.get_lines("Pax"):
    print(line)

# OPTION 3:

for line in Letters().get_lines("Pax"):
    print(line)
```

Comment: Why would _lookup be an instance attribute rather than a class attribute?

Comment: @DarkKnight: no particular reason, unless the constructor may be able to dynamically generate different fonts, for example (though I'd probably look into inheritance at that point). But you're probably right, they could *all* be class variables if no variation is required.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks for the help but, Each word has to be in an nx8 grid and each letter is to use iterations and conditionals. I am not allowed to to use print('***') line by line etc

Comment: @CamarilloMike83: hence the paragraph beginning "But, regardless of how you do the individual letters". The rest of the answer still stands inasmuch as you'll want to return the lines of each letter rather than print them out. That's how you can combine them into a row of letters.